# Ejemplo dudoso en la definición de "cero horas" del DLE

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales, dle

Según el DLE, la expresión *cero horas* significa:

> **[cero horas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8MMZdYY#Fxl06af)**
>
> 1. f. pl. Hora a partir de la que empiezan a contarse todas las demás. *El plazo termina a las cero horas de hoy.*

Si estamos hablando del día *de hoy*, las cero horas será el momento en el que da inicio el día, lo que solemos denominar "las doce de la noche". Luego el ejemplo presentado, "el plazo termina a las cero horas de hoy", no tiene sentido dada la definición puesto que, se diga a la hora que se diga esa frase, las cero horas del día "de hoy" será un momento ya pasado en el tiempo. Yo entiendo que el ejemplo debe ser:

> El plazo terminó a las cero horas de hoy.

O bien:

> El plazo termina a las cero horas de mañana/el jueves/el primero de mes/lo que sea.

También es posible que yo no esté entendiendo bien el ejemplo. ¿Tiene sentido pues el ejemplo dado por la RAE en el DLE para *cero horas*? ¿O deberíamos informar para que lo cambien?

Comment: Tal como lo veo, el ejemplo es incorrecto, en efecto. También me hace ver que usar la expresión *cero horas* no es buena idea en algunos casos, pues puede llevar a error; *el plazo terminó a las cero horas de hoy* tiene un significado claro, pero *terminará a las cero horas del jueves* ya me parece más problemático. Manteniendo el significado del ejemplo del diccionario, yo usaría *el plazo terminará hoy a medianoche*; aunque, claro, ya no nos sirve como ejemplo.

Comment: How strange. When I read the title I assumed _cero horas_ meant the time an event was supposed to happen like H hour in English and from which you could backwards, H-1, H-2 or forwards H+1, H+2. We also have D day of course. Do we not have the same usage in Spanish?

Comment: @mdewey I remember having watched some movies in which the expression "hora H" is used as you say, but then "hora H" would be a previously defined time of a specific day. If you say "cero horas" you refer to a moment that acts as a starting point for something. Hence "cero horas de hoy" is the moment in which the hours of the present day started counting. Now that I think of it, maybe "hora cero" could be used as "hora H", but note that the words are in reversed order.

Comment: @mdewey see this example from the CORDE: _Desde que cierran la cápsula restan algo menos de dos horas hasta la hora cero y el tiempo pasa rápidamente mientras se hace la comprobación final de todos los sistemas eléctricos y mecánicos tanto a bordo de la "Fe 7" [...] como del gran cohete en cuya punta está montada. Cuando faltan 50 minutos para el despegue, la torre de servicio es retirada y quince minutos después, a la hora "T menos 35 minutos", se abren las válvulas y el Atlas ruge llenándose de oxígeno líquido [...]._ (1963)

Comment: That is fascinating. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

Como comenta Gorpik: en efecto, el ejemplo ***El plazo termina a las cero horas de hoy***  es incongruente... por sí solo (ver ejemplo #4).

Las Cero horas de hoy sucedió a las 12:00 AM, así que siempre será una hora que ya pasó.

Para que tenga congruencia podemos hacer distintos cambios:

1.- Agregar tiempo:

> ***El plazo termina a las cero horas con 30 minutos de hoy.*** (Es posible que este plazo aun no se cumpla.)

2.- Cambiar a tiempo pasado:

> ***El plazo terminó a las cero horas de hoy.***

3.- Cambiarlo a mañana:

> ***El plazo termina a las cero horas de mañana.*** (Esto aun no se cumple.)

4.- Agregar el huso horario

> ***El plazo termina a las cero horas de hoy***, hora del pacifico/del centro/hora de México/hora de España.
>
> > Aunque de esta manera conserva el sentido, aun así se necesita elaborar más la idea y solamente funciona en el marco/contexto utilizado... Pero de que puede ser válida, puede ser válida.

Answer (score 2):

Un día tiene, normalmente, 24 horas. Estas van desde las 00.00:00 hasta las 23.59:59.

"Las cero horas" se refiere a la hora 00, la primera de todas.
Incluso cuando corresponde aplicar un [segundo intercalar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segundo_intercalar), la hora pasa de 23.59:59 a 23.59:60 para que ese segundo de más se quede en el día que le corresponde, **y después** se pasa a 00.00:00 para iniciar el día siguiente.

¿Puede tener sentido la frase *"El plazo termina a las cero horas de hoy"*?
Bueno, "cero horas" se refiere a la hora, no a los minutos. La frase no dice *"a las cero horas **en punto**"*, así que que tenga sentido o no depende en parte de cómo de estricta es esa condición del plazo.
Podría darse la siguiente conversación:

> —Ya son las doce y cuarto y todavía están entrando peticiones. ¿Las acepto?
>   —El plazo termina a las cero horas de hoy. No dice en qué minuto. Yo creo que podemos dejar de margen hasta y media.

No obstante, opino que los ejemplos del diccionario deberían ser mucho menos equívocos que este. Y es cierto que "cero horas", aun cuando no se especifica "en punto", suele interpretarse por defecto como las 00.00.
Por tanto, sería más adecuado cambiar el ejemplo para que diga *"El plazo terminó a las cero horas de hoy"* o bien *"El plazo termina a las cero horas de mañana"*.

Comment: Hay una diferencia entre 23.59:60 y 24.00:00.  La hora 24 significa(ría) el final del día (y corresponde(ría) al 0:00:00 del día siguiente;  son, efectivamente, horas sinónimas).  Si el reloj indica 24.00:00 para el segundo intercalar, debe ser un error, el tiempo UTC solo contempla 23.59.60 como el sexagésimo primero segundo del último minuto del día.

Comment: No entiendo el problema: se ve mucho " las cero horas de hoy" en site:.es https://www.google.com/search?q=%22las+cero+horas+de+hoy%22+site%3A.es&oq=%22las+cero+horas+de++hoy%22+site%3A.es&aqs=chrome..69i57.15470j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 También en site:.co y site:.ar O sea, está por todas partes...